# Solving a Recursive equation, wrong options?

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion

This is a very simple recursive formula. Are the options provided wrong?

$$
T(n) = T\left(\frac{n}2\right) + 2
$$
with $T(1) = 1$. What's the solution when $n=2^k$ ($n$ is a power of $2$)?

The answer I got is: $2\log(n) -1$

The options given were

$a)2(\log(n) + 1)$

$b)2\log(n)$

$c)\log(n) + 1$

$d)2\log(n) +1$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/890921/recurrence-relation-with-doubling-stepping-size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer fails fairly early on, since
$$T(2)=T(1)+2=3$$
so $T(2)$ is not $2\log(2) - 1 = 2\cdot 1 -1 = 1$. My advice: always check your solutions.

Comment: Silly, off-by-one error. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

$$n=2^k$$

So,the recursive relation becomes:

$$T(2^k)=T(2^{k-1})+2$$

We set $T(2^k)=S(k)$

$$S(k)=S(k-1)+2$$

$$S(k-1)=S(k-2)+2$$

$$\dots$$

$$S(2)=S(1)+2$$

So,we have $S(k)=S(1)+2 \cdot(k-1) $

$$S(1)=T(2)=3$$

$$S(k)=S(1)+2 \cdot(k-1)=3+2(k-1)=3+2k-2=2k+1 $$

$$S(k)=2k+1 \Rightarrow T(2^k)=2k+1 \Rightarrow T(n)=2 \lg n+1$$